# Removing excess comma in PHP output string

Tags: php, regex, character-trimming

I want to remove the excess comma in my output string inside a parenthesis.

```
 $data= "item_id IN ( '1','2',) AND nt_id IN ( 'er1','er2',) AND";
```

I removed the Excess 'AND' by using rtrim funtion.

```
$trimValues = rtrim($data,'AND') ;
```

But how can I remove the comma inside a parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
,(?=\s*\))
```

You can use this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rkDV4X/1

```
$re = '/,(?=\s*\))/';
$str = 'item_id IN ( \'1\',\'2\',) AND nt_id IN ( \'er1\',\'er2\',) AND';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```